# Filtering with setSubsetString using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, filter, subset

I would like to create a layer with a filter on one of my columns (`"GAMME_DE_S"`). I saw that I can use `setSubsetString` but no way to use it.

```py
uri = r"C:\impression_plan\FicheCana.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "", "ogr")
resultat_layer = layer

layer.setSubsetString("GAMME_DE_S=VSR")
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```py
layer.setSubsetString("GAMME_DE_S=VSR")
```

to

```py
layer.setSubsetString("GAMME_DE_S='VSR'")
```

Then to add the layer

```py
if not layer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

A general tip to avoid issues with syntax in [`setSubsetString`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aba0ee124dcf2d037f3af53d99866c01c) is

- add the layer manually with the GUI
- use the filter on the layer through the GUI
- select the layer in the layer tree in the GUI
- open the QGIS Python console
- type within the Console `iface.activeLayer().subsetString()` and see the string you will need to set in your `setSubsetString`.

You will never do the mistake again and useful for more complex expressions.

Answer (score 10):

**Pay attention to quotes**: Subset string is an expression.

You have to use single quotes for string values. A text placed between single quotes (`'VSR'`) is interpreted as a string. Double quotes will give you the value of the related field value (`"GAMME_DE_S"`). Fields can also be used without quotes as you did (`GAMME_DE_S`). No need for quotes for numbers (`3.14`).

Therefore, you have two options:

1. `"GAMME_DE_S = 'VSR'"`
2. `"\"GAMME_DE_S\" = 'VSR'"`

If you need to use a number, use, for example, `"GAMME_DE_S = 3.14"`