Iterating through layers contained in GeoPackage with the same SubsetString using PyQGIS
I want to iterate through layers contained in a GeoPackage using PyQGIS and select features based on attributes.
I use the same method on two layers in the same GeoPackage. The first correctly filters out the features that I need and keeps all rows. The second which, to my understanding, uses the same method, seems to filter the correct features but deletes all rows.
Am I doing something wrong or is it just QGIS doing QGIS things?
input_gpkg = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.INPUT_GPKG, context)
polygon_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_POLYGON, context)
name_to_select = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INPUT_NAME, context)
project_name = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.PROJECT_NAME, context)
output_folder = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.OUTPUT_FOLDER, context)
template_layout = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.TEMPLATE_LAYOUT, context)
styles_folder = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.STYLES_FOLDER, context)
default_template_path = self.TEMPLATE_LAYOUT_PATH

layer_names = ["boundary", "landuse", 'highway_line', "railway_line", "railway", "place"]
temporary_layers = []
adm_lvl = 0

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# Select and print boundary features if name_to_select is provided
if name_to_select:
    boundary_layer_path = f"{input_gpkg}|layername=boundary"
    boundary_layer = QgsVectorLayer(boundary_layer_path, "boundary", 'ogr')
    if not boundary_layer.isValid():
        feedback.reportError("Boundary layer could not be loaded from the geopackage.")
        return {}
    adm_lvl = self.selectAndPrintBoundaryFeatures(boundary_layer, name_to_select, context, feedback)

# Iterate over all layers and clip them
for layer_name in layer_names:
    layer_path = f"{input_gpkg}|layername={layer_name.strip()}"
    vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(layer_path, layer_name.strip(), 'ogr')

    if not vector_layer.isValid():
        feedback.reportError(f"Layer {layer_name} could not be loaded from the geopackage.")
        continue
    if vector_layer.name() == 'boundary':

        if adm_lvl is not None:
            adm_lvl1 = adm_lvl + 1
            adm_lvl_str1 = str(adm_lvl1)
            filter_expression = f'"admin_level" = {adm_lvl_str1}'
            vector_layer.setSubsetString(filter_expression)
            # this repeats a few times to find the admin_level with the next higher value
            

    if vector_layer.name() == 'landuse':
        feedback.pushInfo(f"Processing landuse layer: {vector_layer.name()}")

        filter_expression = f'"landuse" = "industrial" OR "landuse" = "residential" OR "landuse" = "commercial"'
        vector_layer.setSubsetString(filter_expression)


Would it be possible for you to share a sample of your data with us? What does the beginning of your code look like? How do you specify the vector_layer? BTW, it is suggested to write the expression like: filter_expression = f"admin_level = '{adm_lvl_str1}'", see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396718/filtering-with-setsubsetstring-using-pyqgis

try using single quotes for the values in the second filter expression. E.g., f'"landuse" = \'industrial\' OR "landuse" = \'residential\' OR "landuse" = \'commercial\''

First of all, thank you for your suggestions. I will implement them as soon as I can and see what it brings. For input, both layers were exported from OverpassTurbo as GeoJSON and saved to a geopackage, both work perfektly fine in regular QGIS. I see that I add the beginning of my code, but the Indentation might be off, since I adjustet that manually in my oritinal post

So, I tried your revides expression, couteau, but it still returns a list without any columns.
@Taras thank you as well, but the adm_lvl filter works as intended, so I'd rather not touch it.

Further to @couteau's suggestion of single quotes, I would recommend using f'"landuse" in (\'industrial\', \'residential\',  \'commercial\')', rather than successive OR` clauses.

Same result again. A layer with invisible entries and no columns.
Btw I solved my problem using .selectByExpression(), but the question remans for me why this in particular and pyqgis in general seems to just not be predictable at all. I even encounter differences regarding output or error messages between runs where I did not change either the input data or the script itself
